# Javascript placeholder doesnt show results on Datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables

After we apple the **"oLanguage"** this code blocks It doesnt show search resutls.

**ORIGINAL CODE BLOCKS**

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('table.table tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="'+title+' ARA" />' );
    } );

    // DataTable
    var table = $('table.table').DataTable();

    // Apply the search
    table.columns().every( function () {
        var that = this;

        $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                that
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );
} );
</script>
```

AFTER THE APPLYING **"oLanguage"**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('table.table tfoot th').each(function () {
        $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="'+$(this).text()+' ARA" />');
    });

    // DataTable
    var table = $('table.table').DataTable({
        order: [
          [0, "desc"]
        ],
        paging: true,
        oLanguage: {
          sUrl: "js/dil/LANGUAGE.json",
        }
    });

    // Apply the search
    table.columns().every(function () {
        var that = this;

        $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
            if (that.search() !== this.value ) {
                that
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

*placeholder="'+$(this).text()+' ARA"* works but It doesnt show search results. Before appliying **"oLanguage"** *placeholder="'+title+' ARA"* was working perfectly?

Any opinion?

Comment: What you get in the browser console?

Comment: oLanguage: makes the issue. There isn't any error but placeholder doesn't work by oLanguage: when I add language manually everything is ok. But when I add language url after placeholder doesn't work

Comment: if you delete `order` you still have the problem?

Comment: Order should not delete

Comment: oLanguage: {
          sUrl: "js/dil/LANGUAGE.json",
        }   if I prefer manual language everything is ok but adding url makes matter

Comment: I knowyou should notdelete `order` only to test if is only "lang" or "land and order" de problem. Also you have a extra comma after `.json" ,`

Comment: I did. The same. The order works fine

Comment: can you add a https://jsfiddle.net/ to test.

Comment: I Will when I back to home